# button inside append is not calling function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_form_wrap"); //form wrapper
    var wrapper1 = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var y = 1;
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".add_form_button", function () {
        // f.preventDefault();
        if (y < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            y++;
            // alert('hi');
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div><button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button></div><div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="name"></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        }

    });
});
```

The above is my one function that calls out to another function on a button click to add a field. 
I'm creating a dynamically addable form that has dynamically addable fields. The function for adding the fields is below.

```
$(wrapper1).on("click",".add_field_button", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper1).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder ="name"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});
```

The following is my view.

```
<body>
    <div class= "input_form_wrap">
    <button class="add_form_button">Add another Form</button>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <form action="index.php/home/addForm" method="post">
            <div ><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="name"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is, my button for adding fields does not work when clicked from the .append. I've used the on() function and it still doesnt work! help!

Comment: But you append `.add_field_button` to `wrapper` , not `wrapper1` so your delegated event doesn't match EDIT: indeed you are, i get fooled by wrong HTML indentation  PS: wait, sounds like your HTML is invalid, wrong matching closing `</form>` tag. Please include relevant smaple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the below line:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><div><button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button></div><div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="name"></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

You are trying to attach event to above `.add_field_button` which is outside `$(".input_fields_wrap");` i.e. `wrapper1`

and your `event` to `.add_field_button` is attached to `$(wrapper1).on("click",".add_field_button", function(e){` and it will not find that particular newly added control in `wrapper1`

So change the append to `wrapper` - `wrapper1` and it works fine

```
$(wrapper1).append('<div><div><button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button></div><div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="name"></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); 
^^^wrapper1 here
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/L5gewdu4/1/)**

---

**UPDATE**

**[Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/L5gewdu4/3/)**

*Restructured html*

```
<button class="add_form_button">Add another Form</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class= "input_form_wrap">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form 1</legend>
                <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
                <form action="index.php/home/addForm" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="name"/>    
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Restructured JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var y = 1;
    $(".add_form_button").on("click",function(){
        if(y < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            y++; 
            var cloned=$('.input_form_wrap:first').clone(); //clone the first form
            $(cloned).find('input[type=text]').val(''); //empty textboxes in cloned element
        $(cloned).find('form').children().filter('div').not('div:first').remove(); //keep only one textbox
            $(cloned).find('legend').html('Form '+y); //change legend text
            $(cloned).insertAfter('.input_form_wrap:last');// insert the cloned element before last form                  
        }
   });
   $('.container').on('click','.add_field_button',function(){
       if(x<max_fields)
       {
            x++;
            var cloned=$(this).next('form').find('div:first').clone(); //get its first div
            $(cloned).find('input[type="text"]').val(''); //empty its value
            $(cloned).append('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>'); //add a remove button to cloned element
            $(cloned).insertBefore($(this).siblings('form').find('input[type=submit]')); //append it before submit button
       }
   });

   $('.container').on('click','.remove',function(){
       $(this).closest('div').remove();
       x--; //reduce number of textboxes once its removed
   });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[UPDATED DEMO2](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/L5gewdu4/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var y = 1;
    $(".add_form_button").on("click",function(){
        if(y < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            y++; 
            var cloned=$('.input_form_wrap:first').clone();
            $(cloned).find('input[type=text]').val('');
        $(cloned).find('form').children().filter('div').not('div:first').remove();
            $(cloned).find('legend').html('Form '+y);
            $(cloned).insertAfter('.input_form_wrap:last');                  
        }
   });
   $('.container').on('click','.add_field_button',function(){
       if($(this).next('form').find('input[type="text"]').length<max_fields)
       {//check the length of each input type=text present in that particular form instead of 'x'
            var cloned=$(this).next('form').find('div:first').clone();
            $(cloned).find('input[type="text"]').val('');
            $(cloned).append('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
            $(cloned).insertBefore($(this).siblings('form').find('input[type=submit]'));
       }
   });

   $('.container').on('click','.remove',function(){
       $(this).closest('div').remove();
   });
    $('.container').on('click','.frmRemove',function(){
        if($('form').length<=1)
        {
            alert('Atleast one form should be present');   
            return
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).closest('.input_form_wrap').remove();
            y--;
        }


    })
});
```

Comment: The thing is i have the remove function which deletes the whole of the newly created form, the added on fields just stay there even if i remove the whole code, any suggestions on that?                                        this is the remove function. $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(f){ //user click on remove text
             f.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().remove(); y--;
                  })

    $(wrapper1).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
     e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

Comment: Can you edit the DEMO I've given and show the scenario?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/L5gewdu4/1/ Here, try adding a new form and then add more fields using the add field button, then remove by clicking the remove button just under the first field of the newly added form, you can see the new form gets removed but not the new fields, i know it's a function placement problem, do check it out! Another problem is that the feild gets added on to the last form created!

Comment: your requirement is quite confusing buddy!! So see you want to add a whole set of `form` when you click **add form** button and the newly added form contains a button to add new fields and some one textbox right?

Comment: Yes! The newly created forms have the capability of adding new fields fo itself! Not to anything else.

Comment: @Sid1972 Am restructuring your piece of code and making it better way! is that ok?

Comment: Yes please! Been stuck on this for a day! :)

Comment: @Sid1972 Updated answer.. check and let me know!! :)

Comment: Works wonders :D Thanks man! Btw is there any chance of removing the dynamic forms also?

Comment: yes there is.. and I have found one issue too!! your each form must contain 10 inputs right?

Comment: yes, i stumbled upon the same thing! if the tally adds upto a total of 10, no more fields gets added up! But thanks for this code man! It's an awesome work! If it's not a trouble do share how to remove the dynamic forms! I'll try and fix the field issue! I'm new to jQuery and that's the trouble!

Comment: @Sid1972 There you go!! Please find the updated answer!!

Answer (score 0):

When the following code is executed, the HTML tags are not present. So jQuery cannot bind the click event handlers.

```
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
```

Try adding any handlers post appending HTML code

Comment: I actually did not use the variable to call my function, i used the button class itself everywhere!